# Text under an arrow without braces

Tags: math-mode, arrows, subscripts, braces, underbrace

**Problem:**

Placing text under rightarrow without using solutions such as `\underbrace`.

**Minimal Working Example (MWE)**

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\noindent \textit{x} = 2 $\Rightarrow$ 2 $\cdot$ 2 $\underbrace{\Rightarrow}_\text{2 = \textit{x}}$ \textit{x} $\cdot$ \textit{x} = 2 $\cdot$ 2 $\Rightarrow$ $\textit{x}^2$ = 4 $\hash$
\end{document}
```

**Desired output**

I would like to basically just remove the underbrace and keep the text either under or above the arrow.

**Current output**

[image]

Comment: First of start by writing this as proper math, you should not be using `\textit{x}` but `$x$` and don't go in and out of math. Secondly, writing on top of say `\Rightarrow` is not recommended in writing, it works fine on a black board, but should not be used in typeset texts.

Comment: @daleif Thanks for the recommendations, what do you propose to use instead of rightarrow? Also, if I wish the x to be in italic, how should it be written?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could use `\xRightarrow`. I also recommend writing everything in math mode.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\begin{document}
\noindent$x = 2 \quad\Rightarrow\quad 2\cdot2\quad
\xRightarrow[2=x]{}\quad x \cdot x = 2 \cdot 2\quad \Rightarrow\quad
x^2 = 4$

\noindent or

\noindent$x = 2 \;\Rightarrow\; 2\cdot2\;
\xRightarrow[2=x]{}\; x \cdot x = 2 \cdot 2\; \Rightarrow\;
x^2 = 4$

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks - how do I get the text above the arrow?

Comment: @kexxcream With `\xRightarrow{2=x}`.

Comment: To whoever downvoted that: maybe you should look at the time stamp of the answer before downvoting....

Answer (score 3):

Using `\overset` or `\underset` you can obtain also your desidered output. With `\Rightarrow` command, you will have:

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\begin{document}
\[x = 2 \Rightarrow 2 \cdot 2 \underset{2=x}{\Rightarrow} x  \cdot x = 2 \cdot 2 \Rightarrow x^2 = 4\]

\[x = 2 \Rightarrow 2 \cdot 2 \overset{2=x}{\Rightarrow} x  \cdot x = 2 \cdot 2 \Rightarrow x^2 = 4\]

\end{document}
```

Using `\implies` command instead of `\Rightarrow`:

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}

\begin{document}
\[x = 2 \implies 2 \cdot 2 \underset{2=x}{\implies} x  \cdot x = 2 \cdot 2 \implies x^2 = 4\]

\[x = 2 \implies 2 \cdot 2 \overset{2=x}{\implies} x  \cdot x = 2 \cdot 2 \implies x^2 = 4\]

\end{document}
```

Using, instead, `stackengine` package of @Steven B. Segletes, there are similar options as `\stackon` and `\stackunder`:

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage{stackengine}
\stackMath
\begin{document}
\[x = 2 \implies 2 \cdot 2 \stackon{\implies}{{\scriptstyle 2=x}} x  \cdot x = 2 \cdot 2 \implies x^2 = 4\]
\[x = 2 \implies 2 \cdot 2 \stackunder{\implies}{{\scriptstyle 2=x}} x  \cdot x = 2 \cdot 2 \implies x^2 = 4\]
\end{document}
```